# Is it possible to backup data from a locked android phone?

Tags: backup, storage

So i forgot the PIN number on my old phone which was not rooted, had no recovery software (Cwm, Xrec, etc.) installed on it, and has usb debugging and auto-mount disabled. We don't know the google account associated with the phone. Basically all I have is the phone and a usb cable. Is there a way to get the user data out of it? Adb won't recognise the device btw. I do apologise if it's a stupid question. The phone automatically connected to the wifi, and I'm on Linux, if that helps. But I managed to get into recovery but adb only recognises the device in sideload mode. The files inside the phone is extremely important to me because it contain photo of my family member that were passed away.

Phone: Vivo V7 Plus

I wanted to try brute-force the PIN with program but unfortunately the phone will cool down for 7000 second (3hours+)

**Info**
My phone model: Vivo 7 Plus
USB debugging: Not turned on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123135/discussion-on-question-by-jackson-lim-is-it-possible-to-backup-data-from-a-locke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found a way to unlock my phone (Vivo V7 Plus) without losing any data !
Special thanks to @alecxs for guiding me through the process !

In order to unlock the PIN lock, I open my phone case and short the test point in order to get into EDL mode (**Note: Different phone have different test point, search where is your phone test point before proceed.** )

After successful short the test point, I can see the "Qualcomm port 9008" is open !
[image]

When Qualcomm port 9008 is visible from device manager, I proceed to run the software. So, here is the MAGIC part! I used a tool from MRT but its cracked by a developer called `officialroms`. The different between cracked and original MRT software are cracked version doesn't have to buy additional hardware to make it work.

I clicked on `start` and the program run until it show `all is done`, after that I restart my phone and everything worked !

[image]

**Here is the instructions link that i follow:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUOFvRkmBMc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Enm-8CvGqIY&t=189s