# How can I unlock/root the Vivo Z1?

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot

I have enabled developer options, enabled USB debugging and unlocked bootloader (OEM unlocking).

```
fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
(bootloader) get_unlock_ability: 1
OKAY [ 0.000s]
Finished. Total Time: 0.000s
```

My phone is vivo Z1, its CPU is Snapdragon 660 AIE with Android 9 OS, security patch level 2021-02-01, it is system-as-root and has no ramdisk.

I am unable to unlock the bootloader:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\Android\SDK\platform-tools> .\fastboot oem unlock
FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\ProgramData\Android\SDK\platform-tools> .\fastboot flashing unlock
FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I have installed vivofastboot and vivofastboot_v2, and updated the dlls [source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3686690)

vivofastboot

```
vivo_fastboot bbk unlock_vivo
...
FAILED (remote: unlock fail.)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

vivofastboot_v2

```
vivo_fastboot vivo_bsp unlock_vivo
...
FAILED (remote: check Signature Fail)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

How can I unlock/root the Vivo Z1?

Comment: Archived comments in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129656/discussion-on-question-by-xei-n-how-can-i-manually-root-the-vivo-z1). It'd be great if the troubleshooting part can continue inside the chat until the final clean solution is achieved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to backup data from a locked android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236471/is-it-possible-to-backup-data-from-a-locked-android-phone)